# Edit Passes button not appearing in Wallet when no passes are available

Tags: iphone, ios, wallet

So I have a ticket that I bought digitally and I wanted to add it to Apple Wallet. I opened the App and the only thing that showed up was my debit card. If I now open the app on another phone where the owner already saved tickets and did not delete them, there is an `Edit Passes`-button that allows you to delete old tickets and add new ones.

<sub>Both phones are on the exact same version of iOS, 14.7</sub>


The problem is that I want to add the ticket to the first phone that does not have any tickets and no button says `Scan Code`. I researched and some sources said that I should just scan the QR-Code with my Camera app but that just opens a long string of numbers in my standard browser.

Is this a bug or am I missing a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The company that runs the ticketing system for the ticket you purchased is responsible for providing a way to add a pass to wallet, usually through their app or a valid Apple Wallet link (hence how it could be embedded in a QR code). For example, an airline would have a 'Add to Apple Wallet' button in their app, or email you an 'add to wallet' link.

I'd recommend looking into whether the service you bough the ticket through has an app with wallet capabilities listed towards the bottom of the App Store product page. Otherwise they may not support Apple Wallet and then you'd be out of luck.

Comment: When I bought the ticket in Safari on a MacBook, there was a pop-up that had a QR-Code and also had a button saying `Add to Apple Wallet`. Since that MacBook is a bit of an older model, I always have problems connecting it to my iCloud. That's why the button only adds it to my computer but I don't want to show my computer when I'm boarding a flight.

Comment: You could try getting the pop-up to reappear on your phone through an order confirmation or order history and then pressing the button on there. I'm doubting the QR Code is going to work as, assuming it's the same one you scanned before, it may be corrupted.